# heapsort - implementation's complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, heapsort

I wrote heapsort (Cormen). Algorithm is sorting correctly but complexity is greater than expected.

```
void heap_sort(int tab[], int length)
{
    build_max_heap(tab, length);
    int heap_size = length;
    for (int i = length-1; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int tmp = tab[1];
        tab[1] = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tmp;
        heap_size--;
        max_heapify(tab, 1, heap_size);
    }
}

void max_heapify (int tab[], int i, int length)
{
    int largest;
    int l = i * 2;
    int r = i * 2 + 1;
    if (l < length and tab[l] > tab[i])
        largest = l;
    else
        largest = i;
    if (r < length and tab[r] > tab[largest])
        largest = r;
    if (largest != i)
    {
        int tmp = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tab[largest];
        tab[largest] = tmp;
        max_heapify(tab, largest, length);
    }
}

void build_max_heap(int tab[], int length)
{
    for (int i = length/2; i >= 1; i--)
        max_heapify(tab, i, length);
}
```

For 15000000 numbers generated by rand() it lasted longer than sorting with Shell sort in this implementation:

```
void shell_sort (int tab[], int length)
{
    int x = 2;
    int q;
    do
    {
        x*=2;
        q=2*(length/x) + 1;
        for(int i = q, val, j; i < length; i++)
        {
            val = tab[i];
            for(j = i - q ; j >= 0 and tab[j] > val; j-=q)
            {
                tab[j + q] = tab[j];
            }
            tab[j + q] = val;
        }
    }while (q > 1);
}
```

Test:

```
HEAPSORT
Time for 1000000 elements: 0.336 s
Time for 2000000 elements: 0.732 s
Time for 3000000 elements: 1.142 s
Time for 4000000 elements: 1.595 s
Time for 5000000 elements: 2.034 s
Time for 6000000 elements: 2.513 s
Time for 7000000 elements: 3.023 s
Time for 8000000 elements: 3.51 s
Time for 9000000 elements: 4.02 s
Time for 10000000 elements: 4.558 s
Time for 11000000 elements: 5.095 s
Time for 12000000 elements: 5.595 s
Time for 13000000 elements: 6.183 s
Time for 14000000 elements: 6.7 s
Time for 15000000 elements: 7.367 s

SHELLSORT
Time for 1000000 elements: 0.343 s
Time for 2000000 elements: 0.779 s
Time for 3000000 elements: 1.182 s
Time for 4000000 elements: 1.654 s
Time for 5000000 elements: 2.218 s
Time for 6000000 elements: 2.672 s
Time for 7000000 elements: 3.34 s
Time for 8000000 elements: 3.778 s
Time for 9000000 elements: 4.297 s
Time for 10000000 elements: 4.903 s
Time for 11000000 elements: 4.872 s
Time for 12000000 elements: 5.514 s
Time for 13000000 elements: 6.29 s
Time for 14000000 elements: 6.994 s
Time for 15000000 elements: 7.121 s
```

I repeated the test many times. What's wrong with the algorythm?

Comment: Once the heap is made, to sort it: `while (first != last) { std::pop_heap(first, last--); }`

Comment: Since it's being made for educational purposes I'm not allowed to use `std::pop_heap`. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Well, for organizational purposes I recommend keeping things simpler by writing `make_heap`, `sort_heap`, `push_heap`, and `pop_heap` functions separately, where `sort_heap` is just the 2 liner I wrote above.

Comment: I added the data to the question.

Comment: Are you assuming that the shell sort's average case performance is proportional to N^2? Just from the data you can see that's not true.

Comment: @maksym - the example heap sort code fails to sort the first element in some cases. For example start with {7,3,6,2,5,0,1,4}, and it ends up with {7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6}.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but that was not the issue.

Comment: @maksym - true, the issue seems to be the performance of shell sort. Take a look at the [wiki article for shell sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note, big-O and raw performance have a complicated relationship.  In the case of heapsort, poor memory locality will cause it to scale worse on computers than big-O would suggest.  By contrast shell sort is only very slightly worse than `O(n log(n))` and most of its passes have decent memory locality.

I'm therefore not surprised that they are comparable.

That said, you could try turning `max_heapify` from a recursive function into a loop.  That may avoid a certain amount of stack manipulation.