# Simple and friendly time and space complexity analysis for Heapsort

Tags: c++, sorting, time-complexity, space-complexity, heapsort

I was not able to find a simple and friendly time or space complexity analysis for Heapsort. This is not a duplicate question on stackoveflow.

1. **Worst Time complexity** let's get only this example, for heapsort it is O(n log(n)). How do we easily compute it?

Let's compare with the mergesort algorithm.

***Mergesort***

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)    // T(n), n being the number of elements in arr
{ 
    if (l < r) 
    { 
        ........ // constant operations

        mergeSort(arr, l, m);     // T(n/2) since we apply it on aprox half
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);   // T(n/2) since we apply it on aprox half

        merge(arr, l, m, r);    // c*n , out of scope to analyse merge() 
    } 
}
```

The purpose is to analyse the complexity, not the algorithm itself: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Therefore, if n is the array's number of elements and c is a const, we have:

```
T(n) = c, if n=1
T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + c*n, if n>1
so we can rewrite
T(n) = 2*( 2*T(n/4) + c*n/2 ) +c*n
T(n) = 4*T(n/4) + 2cn
T(n) = 4*( 2T(n/8) + c*n/4 ) + 2cn
T(n) = 8*T(n/8) + 3c
...
T(n) = 2^k * T(n/2^k) + kcn
if we use T(1) that we know => 1 = n/2^k => k = log(n) =>
T(n) = 2^(log(n)) * T(1) + nlog(n)
T(n) = n + nlog(n)
=> nlog(n)
```

Full explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nlPxaC2lTw&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwKedT2KfDMB9YA5DgASZb3U&index=6

Now, let's get the example of heapsort.

I mention I already checked on stackoverflow, but there is no clear answer:
[Analysis of speed and memory for heapsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684339/analysis-of-speed-and-memory-for-heapsort) or
[heapsort - implementation's complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094645/heapsort-implementations-complexity)

***Heapsort***

The purpose is to analyse the complexity, not the algorithm itself: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/

```
// main function to do heap sort 
void heapSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    // Build heap (rearrange array) 
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        heapify(arr, n, i);                       // n/2 * TH(n)

    // One by one extract an element from heap 
    for (int i=n-1; i>0; i--) 
    { 
        // Move current root to end 
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]); 

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap 
        heapify(arr, i, 0);              // (n-1) * TH(i)
    } 
} 

T(n) = c, if n=1
TH is the time complexity for heapify()
T(n) = n/2 * TH(n) + (n-1) * TH(i) , where i is decreasing from n-1 to 1
```

The problem is how to calculate `TH(n) = log(n)`. 
Because based on it, `T(n) = n*log(n)`

Therefore, the code for heapify for which we need to compute TH(n):

```
// To heapify a subtree rooted with node i which is 
// an index in arr[]. n is size of heap 
void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i) 
{ 
    int largest = i; // Initialize largest as root 
    int l = 2*i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1 
    int r = 2*i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2 

    // If left child is larger than root 
    if (l < n && arr[l] > arr[largest]) 
        largest = l; 

    // If right child is larger than largest so far 
    if (r < n && arr[r] > arr[largest]) 
        largest = r; 

    // If largest is not root 
    if (largest != i) 
    { 
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]); 

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree 
        heapify(arr, n, largest);       //  how to express TH in terms of n ?
    } 
}

TH(n) = c, if n=1
worst case when the largest if never root:
TH(n) = c + ? * TH( ? )
```

how to write the recursive expression?

There is also the logical deduction, but let's avoid this strategy:

```
There are log(n) levels. 
Half of the elements will be on the last layer, not touched by heapify().
So log(n) elements are touched. 
This might be a good strategy, but not simple or friendly enough.
```

2. **Space complexity**

How to compute O(1) as space complexity, since we use a heap of n elements? Or maybe the O(1) value is wrong : reference https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/ .

Comment: The height of a complete binary tree containing n elements is log(n)

To fully heapify an element whose subtrees are already max-heaps, we need to keep comparing the element with its left and right children and pushing it downwards until it reaches a point where both its children are smaller than it.

In the worst case scenario, we will need to move an element from the root to the leaf node making a multiple of log(n) comparisons and swaps.

During the build_max_heap stage, we do that for n/2 elements so the worst case complexity of the build_heap step is n/2*log(n) ~ nlogn.